# Intermittent "No Database Selected" in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, forms, connection

Have a PHP/MySQL form with a dropdown box containing a list of 350 names.  When any random name is selected, sometimes it works & displays info about that name from the database, and sometimes the form gives the error "No Database Selected".

Here's what I've tried, pretty much grasping at straws as I'm not a programmer:

- Increasing max_connections in /etc/my.cnf from 200 to 2000 (even though only 4-5 connections are made and it's a lightly used server)
- Changing mysql_pconnect to mysql_connect
- Adding the word true to this connection string:

  $mysql = mysql_pconnect($hostname_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql, true) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
- Changing the word require_once to require on this line:

  [?php require('/home/user/Connections/mysql.php'); ?]
- Enabling MySQL & PHP query & error logging. (no errors logged)

<strike>Here is the code: [removed old bad code]</strike>

Update: Working answer from Rob Apodaca below.

Comment: Are you sure that your `mysql_select_db` call actually always contains a database to select? Make a test output of `$mysql` to see whether there are instances when it is empty.

Comment: I added echo $mysql; and it gives me "Resource Id #3".  I added some additional error handling and it gives me:

SQL Error [256] (1046) No database selected
Query : SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1
On line 65, PHP 5.1.6 (Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `mysql_select_db($database_mysql, $mysql);` appears more than once in your provided script. Since the value of `$database_mysql` does not appear to change, I would remove all of the instances of that line and place it just after the `mysql_pconnect/mysql_connect line`.

Comment: This appears to have worked.  After editing both files exactly as you suggested, I tested selecting random names in the dropdown box over and over and every time, it's working with no errors.  Am getting a couple other people to test and to make absolutely sure, but so far I'm confident in your fix.  Thanks so much Rob!  (BTW, cool last name too.)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with a database connection object (B) that was serialized within another serialized object (A). Sometimes, depending on what had happened prior to object A being unserialized, object B would perform a `mysql_select_db()` call with a null database name as it had been lost.

We littered our code with some echo's of the result of a MySQL query "`SELECT DATABASE()`" until we found where the intermittent loss of the default database was occurring. Hope this helps!